# JavaScript Command Handler Not Running Additional Commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I have a command handler for my discord bot.  It loads the command modules fine, (and console logs indicate as much), but I'm having trouble getting it to execute commands beyond the first command module.  Here's the code:

````
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const prefix = "f$";

const fs = require("fs");
try {
    const files = fs.readdirSync("./commands/");
    let jsFiles = files.filter(filename => filename.split(".").pop() === "js");
    for (const filename of jsFiles) {
        let command = require(`./commands/${filename}`);
        if (!command) return console.error(`Command file '${filename}' doesn't export an object.`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        console.log(`Loaded command: ${command.name}`);
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error loading command: '${err}'`);
}
console.log("Finished loading\n");


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Client ready!");
});

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    //console.log(args);
    let cmdName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    for (const command of client.commands.values()) {
        console.log(command.name);
        console.log(cmdName);
        console.log(command === cmdName);
        if (command.name !== cmdName /*&& !command.aliases.includes(cmdName)*/) return;
        try {
            await command.executor(message, args, client);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Error executing command ${command.name}: '$```{err.message}'`);
        }
    }

});

client.login(TOKEN).catch(err => console.log(`Failed to log in: ${err}`));
````

and in each command module you have this bit:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "command",
    description: "description of command",
    aliases: [],
    executor: async function (message, args, client) {
```

(I have not done aliases for this yet, so alias lines are either empty or remmed out.)

Answer (score 0):

You've incorrectly referenced your variable in the template literal which meant lots of your code was ignored, this likely is the entirety of the problem, it should look like this:

```
console.error(`Error executing command ${command.name}: ${err.message}`);
```

For guidance regarding template literals use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals. If you wanted to use the ``` but have them ignored use this code:

```
console.error(`Error executing command ${command.name}: \`\`\` ${err.message} \`\`\`  `);
```

In addition on your execute function you don't have closing braces so that should be:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "command",
    description: "description of command",
    aliases: [],
    executor: async function (message, args, client) {
// code to be executed
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely following you.  You referenced console.error lines, which I see what you mean regarding those lines being written incorrectly.  However, I'm not seeing where this same error is occurring in the code proper. What am I missing?

Comment: you've not closed your curly braces on module.exports

Comment: Yeah, it's closed in the actual code.   There is no error, the additional commands just don't fire, (but they are loaded successfully.)   It looks like there's an issue with the line:
```
if (command.name !== cmdName /*&& !command.aliases.includes(cmdName)*/) return;
```
First command.name is defined as command1, and if it is command2 being called, it hits the return because command.name and cmdName do not match. (this is correct.)  However, it is not restarting the check with command.name as command2, where command2 would actually execute.  (the console logs do show this.)